# Indicate Max value and position with algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

In Matlab, I can calculate the maximum value of a list and the position of this value by:

```
[maxValue, idxMaxValue] = max(L)
```

How can I indicate the index when describing the algorithm in Latex?

```
v = argmax(L) %for the max value
i = ? %for the idx (position) of the max value
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a complete but [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: `v = max(L) i = maxind(L)` and then describe that `maxind(L)` gives the index within `L` where the max value occurs.